# how to add only modify cache-tags to purger queue on node save?

Tags: 8, caching

I have the purger module installed, when i edit a node and save it without change anything, this is what i see in the purger queue :

[image]

Is it possible to alter the way to add tags in the purger queue ?

I want add just tags who is needed.

Because with the tag menu, on every node save, the whole varnish ll be clear because the menu is on every page.

Comment: The problem is not the purger module but the underlying caching strategies. Your question is suggesting you can accept that menus get outdated. Then you can remove the cache tags from the rendered menu block. But there should be better solutions. The simplest one would be to not use the purger module but invalidate varnish time based, so that the pages are only get outdated for a limited amount of time. A more sophisticated solution would be to lazy-load the menu block client-side.

Comment: um my client publish article at a precise time, i need when the page is edit or publish, refresh with 1 minute interval maximum.
its more complicated because i have listing too, i need to clear the cache for every listing where my article is.
Yes the menu can be outdated if they change item.

Comment: Sorry i don't accept menu get outdated, he need to be refresh if someone add menu when editing a node.
My main problem is as soon as you save the node, all cache-tags present ll be sent to the purger queue. And i want to send just tags who has been modify, like tag-node without the tag menu, of tag menu without the tag node if the contrib as just update the menu title.

Comment: OK, you could decouple node and menu editing. Remove the menu element from node edit and replace it with a link to the dedicated menu edit.

Comment: lol really ? this is true for anything, why the tag paragraph-1 go to the purge queue if i don't edit it ? and i edit just paragraph-2 ? all of this tags ll go to the queue because on node save every tags present ll be sent to the queue. And for performance reason, i think it's better to sent to the queue only item who has been changed.

Comment: Paragraphs are not really a problem in this matter because they only belong to one node. But why lol. In your case it would help to remove the menu edit. You can make this conditional that it is still present when adding a node, because this is usually when you add the menu entry. If you want to change it later you are only one click away to reach the dedicated menu edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106826/discussion-between-kevin-and-4k4).